# Symfony 4: WebTestCase fails (Failed to start the session)

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to setup a simple `WebTestCase` which makes a `GET` request to the given URL using Symfony 4 (and `"phpunit/phpunit": "^6.5"`). However, the test fails with:

> Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by
>   \vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Util\Printer.php; at line 112. (500
>   Internal Server Error)

Test Class:

```
class ControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testGetArticles()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request('GET', '/articles');
        $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Controller (which contains `articles` route:

```
/** @Route(path="articles", name="article_list") */  
public function article_list(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render("article/list.html.twig", array(
        "articles" => $this->entityManager->getRepository("App:Article")->getArticles()
    ));
}
```

framework.yaml:

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    csrf_protection: ~
    session:
        # With this config, PHP's native session handling is used
        handler_id: ~
```

These tests were running fine in Symfony 3, in SF 4 not. What is wrong with this test or configuration?

Comment: See: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/720

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I didn't get why this works with SF 3 but not with SF 4 without using e.g. the `@runInSeparateProcess` annotation. This error occurs on all Tests for me (using SF 4), so I've to annotate each test with `@runInSeparateProcess` ? Feels some kind of wrong to me :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must uncomment session section in config\Packages\test\framework.yaml.

```
session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
```

Comment: Perfect, this works fine! Is this somewhere properly documented?

Comment: 1a) This is documented here: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/configuration/framework.html#storage-id
1b) Best info on what this does I could find was in the repo: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/8f081fe30697b4e053d68f1271d5e27c26a1aa2e/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/MockFileSessionStorage.php

2a) THIS IS DEPRECATED as of 5.3. Use `storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.mock_file`
2b) See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#storage-factory-id